# System.NullReferenceException when making all root node's children to root nodes

Tags: c#, .net, treeview, root, children

To remove the root node without it's children I wrote the following loop:

```
foreach (TreeNode n in treeView_Chpters.Nodes[0].Nodes)
{
    treeView_Chpters.Nodes.Remove(n);
    treeView_Chpters.Nodes.Add(n);
}
```

But if the root node has more children than one, I get an error that says, that n is null.
How can I fix this?

Comment: "What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?" would not have helped me in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying a collection while you are iterating it, that will cause an exception for sure.

In order to avoid that, extract the nodes as an array and then iterate it:

```
var nodes = treeView_Chpters.Nodes[0].Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().ToArray();

foreach (TreeNode n in nodes )
{
    treeView_Chpters.Nodes.Remove(n);
    treeView_Chpters.Nodes.Add(n);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, but firstly Nodes is already an array so you do not have to call ToArray() and secondly the error is still the same then :(

Comment: @Spyrex `Nodes` is not an array, is a collection, more concretely a `TreeNodeCollection`, and you haven't tested it as the code has a missing piece `Cast<TreeNode>` and without it you can't compile it. Try the updated answer.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was a bit hasty with my answer. Thank you for the correction now it works.